# $http giving me a hard time displaying the data in a json file

Tags: angularjs, json, pug

Before I moved it to it's own data folder and started using $http I had the json inside the controller in the app.js file and it was fine, but once I externalized the data it quit working without errors.

My root is as follows

```
-website
    -data
        --slides.json
    -images
        --slide1.jpg
        --slide2.jpg
        --slide3.jpg
    -js
        --app.js
    -views
        --partials
             ---home.html
    -index.html
```

The home page is the view where the slider is contained and it is injected into index.html via `<ui-view>`

This is the home view file

```
<div class="clearfix" ng-controller="sliderController">
    <div class="rev_slider_wrapper">
        <div id="rev_slider" class="rev_slider">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="slide in slides">
                    <img ng-src="/images{{slide.img}}"/>
                    <div class="tp-caption WebProduct-Title tp-title">
                        {{slide.title}}
                        <a class="tp-caption tp-button" ng-href='{{slide.linkto}}'> Click me </a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my app.js with the controller

```
var app = angular.module('Cribs', ['ui.bootstrap', 'ui.router']);

    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
        // Application routes
        $stateProvider
            .state('index', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/home.html'
            })
            .state('listings', {
                url: '/listings',
                templateUrl: 'views/partials/listings-list.html'
            });

        // For unmatched routes
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    }]);

    app.run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", console.log.bind(console));
    });

    app.controller('sliderController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/data/slides.json').success(function(data){
            $scope.slides = data;
        });
    }]);
```

And the json data

```
[
  {
    "title": "Slide 1 Title",
    "linkto": "/listings",
    "img":"/slide1.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "Slide 2 Title",
    "linkto": "/contact",
    "img":"/slide2.jpg"
  },
  {
    "title": "Slide 3 Title",
    "linkto": "/about",
    "img":"/slide3.jpg"
  }
]
```

I have visited every tutorial imaginable, every question asked here, and I still can't figure out the problem. **Can anyone tell me what is happening here? Why don't the slides show up? Could this be a Jade/Pug inconsistency with Angular?** It couldn't be a css issue because if I move the json data back into the controller it works fine.

As you can see the console throws no errors either.

[image]

And the Sources are not 404ing either. They loaded in the DOM

[image]

***EDIT**
I should note, that to prove that I do have access to the data, I wrote in the bottom of a page `<pre>{{slides}}</pre>` and I was able to see my json on the screen

Comment: Show the HTML file generated by jade.

Comment: Try `$scope.slides = data.data;`

Comment: @JBNizet The generated HTML is minimized and compiled together in one big html file with other views. Is it really that necessary to show the HTML?

Comment: Well, I find the jade syntax completely unreadable, and even you are wondering if it could be a jade problem. Seeing the actual HTML template would help.

Comment: ok. I'll re-write this portion

Comment: @JBNizet I re-wrote it in HTML. It should be right

Comment: You rewrote it, but is what you rewrote exactly identical to the **actual** HTML generated by Jade? In your original Jade template, the `.rev_slider_wrapper` is on the same indentation level as `.clearfix(ng-controller="sliderController")`, whereas all the other are indented. How comes they're not on the same level in the rewritten HTML?

Comment: It wasn't in the same indentation. Or at least it's not supposed t be. I may have made a mistake when I pasted it here. You know how SO is. You have to indent to get it to show as code. I may have messed up the indentation when I posted the Jade code. The HTML is right. I re-wrote it instead of bringing up the real HTML because if you thought this was hard to read, you'll have a much harder time reading minified HTML with a bunch of data- attributes being passed in by revolution slider

Comment: I thinned it out to shoe just the relevant code. There is a lot of other code there that goes into forming buttons, and overlays, and just trivial nonsense unrelated to angular. lol

Comment: Don't use `ng-controller` with state templates; set the controller via the state config `controller` property

Comment: Also, the root state URL should be `''`, not `'/'`

Comment: @Phil I took the forward slash off and it didn't find the home page

Comment: If you've changed your code, update your question to match. Can you reproduce the problem in a Plunker?

Comment: I didn't change the code, just removed the forward slash as you recommended. I already tried putting it in Plunker or CODEPEN. There are a lot of dependencies for it to run. If I skim down any further it's just going to be a basic angular app which this isn't

Comment: what do you get when you do a console.log(data) on the data parameter before this line "$scope.slides = data;"

Comment: Removing the `/` **is** changing your code

Comment: @Phil Since it didnt work, I put it back. That's why the code didnt change

Comment: @KiwiHaxer If you're asking if the console logs the actual values, yes. it is reaching and reading the json

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is wrapping, where you set your scope variable with the json data in a $timeout, as it could be loading the data after/before the view cycle is completed.

```
$timeout(function() {
    $scope.slides = data;
});
```